# MSysGit Bash - how to enable Ctrl+Left / Right arrows?

Tags: bash, readline, msysgit

Is there a way to enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> keyboard shortcuts (go to previous / next word) in the Bash console installed with MSysGit?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

At your Bash prompt, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Right-Arrow</kbd> and make note of the output. You should see something like: `^[OD` and `^[OC` or similar. Add the following lines to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\eOC": forward-word
"\eOD": backward-word
```

where you will substitute `\e` for escape (`^[`) and the rest of the characters you got (`OD`, `OC` or similar).

To re-read the file and make the changes active immediately, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>.

Answer (score 46):

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/56404) by tan on AskUbuntu, which worked for me after none of these answers did.  I'll repost it here.

What is in your `~/.inputrc` and `/etc/inputrc`? The minimum to get those keys working is, I think:

```
# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

If you have these in `/etc/inputrc`, the **file needs to be included from `~/.inputrc`,** so check that it has the following line:

```
$include /etc/inputrc
```

Comment: You totally nailed it with the `$include /etc/inputrc`. I've created a keyboard shortcut in my `~/.inputrc` (just for fun) and been screwed ever since, because creating the file in my home skipped the `/etc/inputrc` as a default. Thx from the future.

Comment: This works for the MINGW64 client ("Git Bash" in Git for Windows) as well!

Comment: This works for macOS (Mojave, don't know if it counts) terminal as well, thanks !

Answer (score 16):

Not really answering your question, but you can try <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> instead.

Answer (score 7):

Adding to my ~/.inputrc

```
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
```

Was enough for me.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me in Windows 7:

Add this to the `~/.inputrc`
Then restart the console and it should work for you.

This makes it so you can do either use

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

Or

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

```
## Windows msysgit
## Alt + right/left
"\e\e[C": forward-word     ### Alt + right
"\e\e[D": backward-word    ### Alt + left
## Ctrl + right/left
"\e[C": forward-word       ### Ctrl + right
"\e[D": backward-word      ### Ctrl + left
```

Comment: Points to you for specifying a windows 7 solution

Answer (score 2):

For those confused on why it is not working for the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right-Arrow</kbd>.

This is because of a bug with windows 7, maybe others, and msys where the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key would not be recognized (at least for my case).

To check if you are in the same situation, do what @Dennis say:

- Open terminal
- Make sure <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> has not been remapped to something else
- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd> to check the key sequence
- Look at the output

Repeat with only pressing the <kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd>.

If they are identical, welcome to my world. You can now use [Autohotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) to remap the keys or use the newer [windows git bash](https://git-scm.com/).

Comment: How do I "Make sure ctrl+v has not been remapped to something else" ?

Answer (score 1):

I edited the file /etc/inputrc:

```
      sudo gedit /etc/inputrc
```

and commented ***out*** the following lines:

```
      $if term=rxvt
      "\e[8~": end-of-line
      "\eOc": forward-word
      "\eOd": backward-word
      $endif
```

Then I edited the file ~/.bashrc:

```
      sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and added the following lines at the bottom:

```
      #### enable Ctrl+Left , Ctrl+Right keybindings:
      bind '"\e[1;5C":forward-word'   # Ctrl+Right
      bind '"\e[1;5D":backward-word'  # Ctrl+Left
```

It seems to work and, at least so far, without side effects.

(tested on Ubuntu GnomeShell Remix 12.04 AMD64)